# Are there specific vegetables I should not be feeding a rabbit?

Tags: diet, rabbits

My sister's rabbit is given a variety of vegetables (carrots, peppers, lettuce (not iceberg), and so on). Basically, my sister gets whatever is available, and gives the rabbit bits of whatever we have for fresh vegetables.

Are there any vegetables we should avoid giving the rabbit? Or is anything fair game?

Comment: The answer for this question is long and complex, but my starting point would be the [Suggested Vegetable List at rabbit.org](http://rabbit.org/suggested-vegetables-and-fruits-for-a-rabbit-diet/).

Comment: Also see [partial list of plants that are toxic to rabbits](http://www.adoptarabbit.com/articles/toxic.html)

Answer (score 7):

Aside from everything else, the main part of your rabbit's diet should always be **hay**, usually timothy hay (or alfalfa for young rabbits).

Most trusted sites ([House Rabbit Society](http://rabbit.org/), as previously mentioned; as well as [My House Rabbit](http://www.myhouserabbit.com/tip_food.php)) will tell you similar information about what you should be feeding your rabbit.

Regarding [vegetables](http://www.myhouserabbit.com/tip_food.php) specifically:

> A varied assortment of vegetables should be a part of your rabbit's daily diet. When choosing vegetables look for something fresh and free of pesticides. Always wash your vegetables thoroughly before feeding them to your rabbit. Feed new vegetables in small quantities until you can judge if your rabbit reacts well to them. Do not feed rabbits the leaves from houseplants as many are poisonous to rabbits.  Your rabbit may enjoy some of the following vegetables:
>
> - Basil
> - Bok choy
> - Broccoli leaves (stems or tops can make rabbits gassy)
> - Carrot tops (carrots are high in calcium and should be given sparingly)
> - Celery
> - Cilantro
> - Clover
> - Collard greens
> - Dandelion leaves
> - Dill
> - Kale (sparingly)
> - Lettuce - romaine or dark leaf (no iceburg lettuce and no cabbage)
> - Mint
> - Mustard greens
> - Parsley

Although that list is specific to that site, I would steer clear of [cruciferous vegetables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruciferous_vegetables) altogether, which includes broccoli and cauliflower, as rabbits will get bloated and are not able to pass built-up gas.

High-oxalate vegetables such as kale should also be given sparingly, as they can cause complications in a rabbit such as [bladder stones](http://www.thebrc.org/diet.htm) which can only be corrected through expensive surgery.

Pellets and treats should also be give *in moderation*, and infrequently.

[image]

It would be beneficial to research what foods are okay for your rabbit to eat, by looking at some of the resources.  It is not suggested practice to just give your rabbit whatever you can find in your fridge, as many vegetables and other foods can be harmful to their diet.

Comment: +1 This is a very good answer, that focuses mostly on what is good, and only lightly brushes on what to avoid. The question is asking specifically about what to avoid, but that answer is not black and white, there is much grey area. The message here is to focus on feeding good stuff, the list of 'not always good', is long and there are complex rules about quantity and timing.