# One of my three pet bunnies jumped out of the hutch and we can't catch her

Tags: rabbits

I have 3 pet bunnies. One male mini rex and two female black Dutch. One of the females jumped out of the hutch two weeks ago and we have all tried to catch her with no success. I see her every night out at the hutch with the other two, but when I go out,... She runs away. What to do?

Answer (score 6):

The three primary methods for recapturing a domestic rabbit, who is loose.  These options are over simplified.  If you have specific questions about a specific method please post a new question.

1. Call them, this takes some pre-training, but many rabbits have learned it without the pet-parent realizing it. Proper [feeding of a pet rabbit limits pellets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6263/food-pellet-is-my-rabbit-eating-enough/6269#6269) so when you take them their daily serving of pellets they will come running to you and jump in the cage.  They can also very easily be trained to come for treats. With more handling they will come just for snuggles, not as dependably as a dog, but much more than a cat.
2. Corral; using sides of a building, and portable fencing (black 2 foot exercise pen shown in photo) place feed in the pen area, leaving one side open so they can easily walk in.  When they go in and are eating, close the pen.  Make the area smaller by folding the panels, place a pet carrier on the ground with the door open and gently herd the rabbit into the carrier. 
   [image]
3. Live trap cage, we often use this for bunnies that have been released, and the other two methods don't work.  Put food in the cage, and when they come it they get trapped.  Though often it is not as simple as that, but that is a whole another Q&A.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take the other two in doors tonight and put some food inside the hutch with the door open, once she goes in close the door. Add the other two bunnies and you're all done.