# will my rabbit return to her 3 kits, she jumped out of her hutch while feeding her

Tags: rabbits

My pet female bunny had 3 kits in her hutch that she has been taking good care of. They are 10 days old. However, she accidently jumped out while I was feeding her and I can't catch her. Will she return late tonight to nurse them?

Comment: I am desperate for help. I'm leaving both doors open in hopes that she jumps back up into her pen where the kits are. I can see her running around in my back yard and she seems curious about the hutch like she knows the kits are there, but she doesn't know what to do.i have tried all morning to catch and I can't.

Comment: Did you try reading [One of my three pet bunnies jumped out of the hutch and we can't catch her](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7252/one-of-my-three-pet-bunnies-jumped-out-of-the-hutch-and-we-cant-catch-her-this?rq=1)

Comment: I just want to know if there is a chance that the female will return to nurse her 3 baby bunnies, (KITS)if I leave the door to her hutch open. The kits are inside the hutch in the box.

Comment: Does the hutch have a place for mom to get up and away from the kits?