# Feral Bunny with fleas, how can I help it when I'm unable to get more than two feet close?

Tags: health, rabbits

looks like a dwarf bunny. black and white in color how can I rid it of Fleas as I cannot get close because it's feral.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike cats; released domestic rabbits, transition back into domestication very well.  As I write this there is a rabbit sleeping on my bed, who was released in to a neighborhood a few years ago. [Domestic rabbits do not do well in the wild.](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/can-i-release-my-pet-rabbit-in-the-wild)

The very best thing you can do is capture the bunny and get it into the local shelter system.  See [One of my three pet bunnies jumped out of the hutch and we can't catch her](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7252) for some ideas to catch the rabbit.  Depending on where you live there may be a local rabbit rescue who can assist.

Once the rabbit is caught it can be treated with [something like Revolution](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/925/how-do-i-get-rid-of-fleas-on-my-rabbit) which will also treat other parasites.

The rabbit can then go on to live a long and happy life in someones home.

Answer (score -3):

Put out some Daminix and hope that the rabbit finds if and uses it as nesting material?

Wild animals have parasites. That's the nature of nature....

Comment: Feral DOES NOT EQUAL Wild, nor does a released domestic equal natural.

Comment: Fact remains, an animal living outside on its own picks up parasites. The most you can hope for in this case is a temporary reduction.

Comment: :) while your point is valid, it is kind of like putting on a seat belt as you plummet over a cliff, after driving off the road and before you hit the bottom. The ride to the bottom might be a bit safer, but the outcome is the same and it really doesn't change the timeline.

Comment: Not arguing, @jamesjenkins, but unless your point is that the original question is unrealistic -- which I don't disagree with, though there is a faint chance the damminix might do the requested job if the OP is willing to spend the money -- I'm not sure about the relevance...?